# How to deploy neo4j app on Heroku using jruby and rails

Tags: heroku, neo4j, jruby

Trying to deploy `neo4j with jruby` application on `heroku` and `heroku logs` shows this:

```
Neo4j has been shutdown using storage_path: /app/db/neo4j-production
```

**App config is as follows:**

```
## config/application.rb 

    # Configure where the neo4j database should exist
      config.neo4j.storage_path = "#{config.root}/db/neo4j-#{Rails.env}"
```

Any ideas what can be wrong ?

1.for my heroku app I am using this [heroku neo4j addon](https://addons.heroku.com/neo4j)

2.here is [a sample neo4j rails app repo](https://github.com/andreasronge/neo4j-rails-example) that I used for my repo.

Logs:

```
2014-01-18T08:10:25.821598+00:00 app[web.1]: Puma 2.7.1 starting...
2014-01-18T08:10:25.821864+00:00 app[web.1]: * Min threads: 0, max threads: 16
2014-01-18T08:10:25.822353+00:00 app[web.1]: * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:30912
2014-01-18T08:10:25.822137+00:00 app[web.1]: * Environment: production
2014-01-18T08:10:26.828468+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2014-01-18T08:10:27.898102+00:00 app[web.1]: Error in reactor loop escaped: Bad file descriptor - Bad file descriptor (Errno::EBADF)
2014-01-18T08:10:27.898602+00:00 app[web.1]: org/jruby/RubyIO.java:3673:in `select'
2014-01-18T08:10:27.898993+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/puma-2.7.1-java/lib/puma/reactor.rb:125:in `run_in_thread'
2014-01-18T08:10:27.898803+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/puma-2.7.1-java/lib/puma/reactor.rb:28:in `run_internal'
2014-01-18T08:10:31.824933+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2014-01-18T08:10:31.828398+00:00 app[web.1]: Error in reactor loop escaped: Bad file descriptor - Bad file descriptor (Errno::EBADF)
2014-01-18T08:46:02+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2014-01-18T08:48:29.793444+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 47971a8 by xxx@gmail.com
2014-01-18T08:48:29.826435+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v7 created by xxx@gmail.com
2014-01-18T08:48:29+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2014-01-18T08:48:30.063859+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2014-01-18T08:48:32.412033+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2014-01-18T08:48:33.017499+00:00 app[web.1]: Neo4j has been shutdown using storage_path: /app/db/neo4j-production
2014-01-18T08:48:34.447765+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2014-01-18T08:48:37.928763+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server puma -p 20055 -e $RACK_ENV`
2014-01-18T08:48:38.903302+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Djava.rmi.server.useCodebaseOnly=true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like your path is wrong. You certainly know that Heroku doesn't offer persistent storage? OpenShift does though.

On Heroku I'd go with the hosted [GrapheneDB](https://addons.heroku.com/graphenedb) offering. Then you can use [neography](https://github.com/maxdemarzi/neography) or [neo4j.rb](https://github.com/andreasronge/neo4j) (in server mode) to connect to your neo4j db.

See also http://neo4j.org/develop/ruby